# JOIN con una columna calculada

Tags: sql-server, join

No puedo crear este join en SQL de una tabla. Necesito crear la concatenación de los números que se repiten que es lo que construí como *tabla1* y tengo que hacer el join con la construcción de la tabla de abajo. Quiero que esta nueva construcción sea la que aparezca al final en la tabla, pero no sé si construir al principio *tabla1* y después querer hacer el join sea correcto.

Quiero saber si como lo estoy presentando es correcto o debo hacer algo diferente.

```
 select * from  (SELECT DISTINCT
           SERIAL,
           STUFF(
           (
           SELECT
                  '***/NP***:' + T2.ITEM_DESCR
           FROM
               DB2_SHORTAGES AS T2
           WHERE
               T2.SERIAL = T1.SERIAL
           AND SHORT_TYPE_CD='E'
           ORDER BY
               T2.ITEM_DESCR
           FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE      
           ).value('.[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') AS ITEM_DESC
    FROM
           DB2_SHORTAGES AS T1)   
           as tabla1 
    
    
    select 
    VW_OFF_WIPVehicles.VEH_SER_NO as serial,
    VW_FLEET_DATA.CUST_NAME_ABBR as Customer,
    VW_FLEET_DATA.MDL as Model,
     DATEDIFF (DAY,VW_OFF_WIPVehicles.ENTER_TIME,getdate())   AS DiO,
      DATEDIFF (DAY,DB2_CRIES.OTD,getdate())   AS OTD,
      DB2_CRIES.E as E,
      DB2_CRIES.OP_SC as SC,
      tabla1.ITEM_DESC
    from VW_OFF_WIPVehicles
                  left join VW_FLEET_DATA
                  on VW_OFF_WIPVehicles.VEH_SER_NO=VW_FLEET_DATA.FLEET
                  left join DB2_CRIES
                  on VW_OFF_WIPVehicles.VEH_SER_NO=DB2_CRIES.SERIAL
                  left join tabla1
                  on VW_OFF_WIPVehicles.VEH_SER_NO=tabla1.SERIAL
    order by OTD desc
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Ademas de este codigo, necesitamos ver que sale actualmente, y como queres que salga...

Comment: Más que todo ese código, a tu pregunta le vendría bien un [mcve], eso aumentaría tus probabilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas.